# How can I eliminate the small extra column on the right and the extra row on the bottom of my html table

Tags: html, css, csv

I have a csv file that I load into an 11 column html table. The data displays as expected except there is a very narrow column on the far right. There is also an extra blank row at the bottom. I have made dozens of adjustments to the width percentages but the little column on the right prevails. I haven't tried to eliminate the extra row on the bottom because I don't know what to try. See CSS code.

```
<title>CSV to HTML5</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    table {
        width: 850px;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    th {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 6px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    tr {
        height: 24px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #00FFFF;
    }

    td {
        font-family: Arial, Verdana;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        cellpadding: 3px;
    }

    td:nth-child(1) {
        width: 4%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    td:nth-child(2) {
        width: 6%;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    td:nth-child(3) {
        width: 14%;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    td:nth-child(4) {
        width: 14%;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    td:nth-child(5) {
        width: 18%;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    td:nth-child(6) {
        width: 6%;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    td:nth-child(7) {
        width: 5%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    td:nth-child(8) {
        width:8%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    td:nth-child(9) {
        width: 8%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    td:nth-child(10) {
        width: 8%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    td:nth-child(11) {
        width:8%;
        text-align: center;

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <legend>
                <h1 id="clubname" style="text-align:center"></h1>
                <h2 id="racename" style="text-align:center"></h2>
                <h3 id="racedate" style="text-align:center"></h3>
            </legend>
        </div>
        <div id="output">
        </div>
        <div id="myDiv" class="container">
            <hr>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inp_clubname" placeholder="Club Name" size="24" required>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inp_racename" placeholder="Race Name" size="24" required>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inp_racedate" placeholder="Date Name" size="24" required>
                    <label for="csvFileInput">CSV File: </label>
                    <input type="file" id="csvFileInput" onchange=accept=".csv" size="35" required>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="generate()" value="Generate" />
                </div>
            </form>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <p style="text-align:center">©: Klexy Soft</p>
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function generate() {
        console.log('generate called')
        //copy text from form to headings
        ids = ["clubname", "racename", "racedate"]
        for (i in ids) {
            value = document.getElementById('inp_' + ids[i]).value
            document.getElementById(ids[i]).innerHTML = value
        }

        files = document.getElementById('csvFileInput').files
        // Check for the various File API support.
        if (window.FileReader) {
            // FileReader are supported.
            var reader = new FileReader();
            // Read file into memory as UTF-8
            reader.readAsText(files[0]);
            // Handle errors load
            reader.onload = loadHandler;
            reader.onerror = errorHandler;
        } else {
            alert('FileReader is not supported in this browser.');
        }
    }

    function loadHandler(event) {
        var csv = event.target.result;
        processData(csv);
    }

    function processData(csv) {
        var allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        var lines = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
            var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
            lines.push(data);
        }
        //console.log(lines);
        drawOutput(lines);
    }

    function errorHandler(evt) {
        if (evt.target.error.name == "NotReadableError") {
            alert("Canno't read file !");
        }
    }

    function drawOutput(lines) {
        //Clear previous data
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            var row = document.createElement("TR");
            table.appendChild(row)
            for (var j = 0; j < lines[i].length; j++) {
                // first row is header
                cell = document.createElement(i == 0 ? "TH" : "TD");
                row.appendChild(cell)
                cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(lines[i][j]));
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("output").appendChild(table);
        document.getElementById("myDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    console.log('initialized')
    </script>
</body>
```

csv file

```
PL,Sail#,Yacht,Type,Skipper,Club,Rtg,Finish,Elapsed,Cor'ted,  1st +,
```

1,1234,Boat Name,42MkII,Name,GYC,115,14:10:53,02:00:53,01:46:42,00:00:00,
2,1234,Boat Name,4000,Name,GYC,107,14:16:29,02:06:29,01:53:17,00:06:35,
3,1234,Boat Name,Catalina36MKII,Name,GYC,144,14:26:34,02:16:34,01:58:48,00:12:06,
4,1234,Boat Name,42,Name,GYC,131,14:26:37,02:16:37,02:00:28,00:13:46,
5,1234,Boat Name,Mark3,Name,GYC,218,14:52:01,02:42:01,02:15:08,00:28:26,
6,1234,Boat Name,Nonsuch 30C,Name,GYC,156,14:54:43,02:44:43,02:25:29,00:38:47,
7,1234,Boat Name,KP44,Name,GYC,168,15:25:50,03:15:50,02:55:07,01:08:25,

Comment: Provide us HTML also

Comment: In the CSV, every line ends with a comma, causing the `data` variable to have an extra empty field at the end after the `split(',')`. So the problem had nothing to do with the CSS.

Comment: You have identified one of the problems...the comma at the end of each line, however there are still two borders on the right side, and I still have the extra empty row at the bottom.

Comment: By testing I learned that if the cell border specifications do not match exactly the table border specifications you may get two right hand borders. My solution, remove the cell borders and let the table borders govern. Now all of the border problems are gone. But I still have the extra blank row at the bottom.

Comment: @EdJenkins Hm. Does the CSV file end with a blank line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems I was having was the java script, function drawOutput(lines) { and the codes that perform the function, generates the table and adds an extra blank row at the bottom, I guess waiting for another line of data. By adding one more line to the java script function code, the very last line, I was able to remove the extra empty row.

```
document.getElementById("output").appendChild(table).deleteRow(-1);
```